# How to iterate and extract values out of a for loop in Rust

Tags: for-loop, rust

I'm new to Rust and looking to understand concepts like borrowing. I'm trying to create a simple two dimensional array using standard input. The code:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut values = [["0"; 6]; 6]; // 6 * 6 array

    // iterate 6 times for user input
    for i in 0..6 {
        let mut outputs = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut outputs).expect(
            "failed to read line",
        );

        // read space separated list 6 numbers. Eg: 5 7 8 4 3 9
        let values_itr = outputs.trim().split(' ');
        let mut j = 0;
        for (_, value) in values_itr.enumerate() {
            values[i][j] = value;
            j += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This won't compile because the `outputs` variable lifetime is not long enough:

```
error[E0597]: `outputs` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
14 |         let values_itr = outputs.trim().split(' ');
   |                          ------- borrow occurs here
...
20 |     }
   |     ^ `outputs` dropped here while still borrowed
21 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

How can I get the iterated values out of the block into values array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`split()` gives you substrings (string slices) borrowed from the original string, and the original string is `outputs` from line 6.

1. The string slices can't outlive the scope of `outputs`: when a loop iteration ends, `outputs` is deallocated.
   Since `values` is longer lived, the slices can't be stored there.
2. We can't borrow slices of `outputs` across a modification of `outputs`. So even if the `String` `outputs` itself was defined before `values`, we couldn't easily put the string slices from `.split()` into `values`; modifying the string (reading into it) invalidates the slices.

A solution needs to either

- Use a nested array of `String`, and when you assign an element from the split iterator, make a `String` from the `&str` using `.to_string()`. I would recommend this solution. (However an array of `String` is not at as easy to work with, maybe already this requires using `Vec` instead.) <sup>1</sup>
- Read all input before constructing a nested array of `&str` that borrows from the input `String`. This is good if the nested array is something that you only need temporarily.

<sup>1</sup>: You can use something like `vec![vec![String::new(); 6]; 6]` instead

Comment: It would be ideal if I can solve this using arrays. But seems there is no way to create an array of Strings in Rust. Isn't it? First method works fine with the Vectors. Thanks for the answer.. (including your last remarks on IRC) 
"value is a &str, a substring from outputs. so .to_string() allocates space for a String and copies the substring into that. so value was a &str (a reference) but is turned into a String. since it's not a reference it's not restricted by the borrow checker or the life of `outputs`."

Comment: There's no *nice* way to create an array of strings. `[[String::new(), String::new(), String::new(), String::new(), String::new(), String::new()], [String::new(), String::new(), String::new(), String::new(), String::new(), String::new()], ...]` certainly isn't nice.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was moved from the question, where it solved the OPs needs.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut values = vec![vec![String::new(); 6]; 6];
    for i in 0..6 {
        let mut outputs = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut outputs)
                .expect("failed to read line");

        let values_itr = outputs.trim().split(' ');
        let mut j = 0;
        for (_, value) in values_itr.enumerate() {
            values[i][j] = value.to_string();
            j += 1;
        }
    }
}
```